# QtCore Module not found using PySide2 on Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pyside2

With a python file containing the two lines

```
import PySide2
from PySide2 import QtCore
```

The execution from Anaconda Prompt on Windows 10 looks as follows

```
(base) c:\src\pyside2>python ps2-first.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ps2-first.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PySide2 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

So the first import executed correctly, but it couldn't find the QtCore module.

Background:

Installed PySide2 using

```
(base) c:\src\pyside2>conda config --add channels conda-forge
(base) c:\src\pyside2>conda install pyside2
```

Which succeeded. Also, versions of conda and python are shown here:

```
(base) c:\src\pyside2>conda --version
conda 4.7.10

(base) c:\src\pyside2>python -V
Python 3.7.1
```

Checking for PySide 2 installation:

```
(base) c:\src\pyside2>conda list pyside2
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pyside2                   5.9.0a1          py37h0555040_0    conda-forge
```

This DLL is in the path: pyside2.cp37-win_amd64.dll

Comment: There seems to be a version compatibility issue with this version of Anaconda and PySide2 from conda-forge. When I re-installed Anaconda, the added PySide2 with these commands (from the front page of conda-forge), 

"conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda install pyside2"

Then the dependency ground for a few hours, then spat out "incompatible with pip" -- along with hundreds of other lines of analysis.

Comment: I also uninstalled pyside2 using "conda uninstall pyside2" and tried installing with pip. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be that your project folder name is `pyside2` and Windows is case insensitive. So it is possible that python interpreter try to search `QtCore` inside your project folder.

If this not help please run `python -v -c "from PySide2 import QtCore"` and add log to your question.

The other problem can be that some dependencies of `pyside2.cp37-win_amd64.dll` can be missed. then loading of this library also will fail. 
You can check dependencies of dll by [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: Thank you, Grzegorz, Dependency Walker returned several missing things, two of which are

QT5CORE_CONDA.DLL and
QT5QML_CONDA.DLL, 

along with many
API-MS-WIN-CORE* DLLs, some of which are available in the conda distribution, and some of which are not in the path missing.

Perhaps my installation is simply incomplete. I have since uninstalled everything python, Qt, and Anaconda related. Re-installed Anaconda and gotten the same errors.

Comment: I have updated response. The problem can be name of your project folder.